# Remote network SLES install error on ia64

Tags: linux, sles, automated-install, novell, itanium

Does anyone have any experience installing SLES though lanboot on ia64?
I have done plenty of network SLES installs for i386 and x86_64, even PowerPC, but for some reason ia64 is stumping me.

I have my elilo.conf file set up properly to install RHEL, but I can't seem to find the right kernel image for SLES. I've looked in the boot/ia64 directory on the SLES disk, but nothing there seems to allow me to boot up.

Unfortunately Novell has very little documentation on ia64, and none on ia64 network installs.
I have this issue for all new versions of SLES, it does not seem limited to SLES10 or SLES11.

FYI, here is a sample section of my elilo.conf file:

```
#This 'image' file seems to be invalid
image = iso_images/sles-10-sp3/ia64/boot/ia64/image
    label = sles-10-sp3-pos
    append = "ip=dhcp install=http://<IP>/files/iso_images/sles-10-sp3/ia64/ vnc=1 vncpassword=PASS autoyast=http://<IP>/files/autoyast/sles-10-sp3.xml console=ttyS1,115200n8r console=tty0"
    initrd = iso_images/sles-10-sp3/ia64/boot/ia64/initdisk.gz
```

And this is what the output looks like on the server:

```
Client MAC Address: <MAC> ..
Client IP Address: <IP>
Subnet Mask: <SUBNET>
BOOTP Server IP Address: <IP>
DHCP Server IP Address: <IP>
Boot file name: elilo.efi

Retrieving File Size.
Retrieving File (TFTP).
ELILO boot: sles-10-sp3-pos
elilo.c(line 83):Cannot find a loader for iso_images/sles-10-sp3/ia64/boot/ia64/image
Exit status code: Load Error
```

Does anyone know where I can find the correct kernel image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your ELILO seems to work. [Try this one](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/doc/suse/sles9/adminguide-sles9/ch04s03.html)
When setting up an install-server in our environment I used the pxe-image provided by Ubuntu 10.4 LTS - perhaps this is a good idea for EFI, too (if Ubuntu has one).

The reason was that the Ubuntu version was newer and provided more features.

Comment: Yes, that guide was exactly what I needed.
I simply needed to unpack the image file, that contains the linux kernel image and initrd that I need.